# LED Bike light - blowing at high speeds?

Tags: led, generator

My bicycle is equipped with a about 5 year old hub dynamo and a LED front- and backlight.
I suspect the dynamo is a DC-generator though this likely may be false. But if its true, it would mean that with rising rpm I have rising voltage as well, which probably could cause some trouble at really high speeds.

My question is: Would going fast enough on my bike make the LEDs (or other parts of the lighting system) blow? What are feasible ways to test if the dynamo output voltage is limited?

Comment: Generally yes but specifically we have no details of your system and possible circuit protectors.

Comment: I read somewhere that, some dynamos have a zener diode inside, limiting the maximum voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most dynamos produce a dirty 6v AC, depending on how fast you are going. I don't know how they've done it, but the engineers responsible for your bike lights probably included some rectification to convert the AC to DC and maybe even integrated some circuitry to limit the voltage/current going to the leds.

**TLDR; No, you'll be fine.**

So, if you wanted to make your own bike lights:

- assume your dynamo outputs 6ish volt AC or more or less
- convert this AC to DC with a bridge rectifier
- add a big capacitor to smooth out this really sketchy power source
- hook up your LEDs and resistor(s) in a way that they will survive the most extreme scenario
  OR
- come up with some voltage/current limiting magic

Comment: How about feeding the output of the bridge rectifier into a buck/boost converter (which contains a capacitor)? Would the input need smoothing first?

Comment: Those converters are used to lower or raise the (known) input voltage. Since in this case the input voltage isn't constant, using a b/b seems unnecessary. In this case, I think bridge rectifier -> voltage regulator -> cap(s) -> LED(s) and resistor is the best way to go.

Comment: You can also buy a [bridge-rectifier](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062580) IC that will output a fully-rectified signal. Just add the appropriate capacitors across the output sufficient to supply your required current without dropping too much voltage and you'll be good to go. Powering LEDs only is not big feat. You may also consider just driving the LEDs with the 6V AC if the frequency is high enough. You may (likey will) get some flickering back that will only make you more visible in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer for my obviously off-topic question and correcting my wrong thoughts about dynamos!

Answer (score 2):

If the LED lights were supplied with the dyno or intended to be used with it then it should work OK as you'd *expect* the designers to be aware of the requirements. This is not always true, alas.

If the Dyno was designed with LED lights in mind OR if the LED lights were designed with industry standard dynos in mind then the same arguments apply.

However, in the most general case a hub dyno has an increasing voltage output with speed and a current output limited mainly by saturation of some part of the magnetic circuits involved. This means that maximum available power rises (very) approximately with speed and if it is adequate to run your lights at full brightness at sensible speeds it may be able to destroy them at nonsensically fast speeds if the light designer has not anticipated the not unusual extremes of human behaviour. Nonsensically fast speeds at night using bike lights is liable to destroy you too so are best avoided regardless :-).

If you have a rechargeable battery which is charged by your dyno then this will usually limit the maximum voltage and protect your lamps.

If you wish to test this try placing the bike upside down or on test stand and gradually wind up speed with dyno driving lights. If lights get to maximum brightness at some speed and do not keep getting brighter thereafter then offs are the system is integrated correctly. If there is no obvious point at which brightness increase flattens out with rising speed you may 'have problems'.

It WILL be possible to protect LED lights against any dyno.
If the above (especially speed test) does not answer your questions please provide details of results achieved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have not the equipment to do a speed test at higher speeds than driving downhill an asphalt road, so I can´t do that, but my curiousity is reasonably conformed. +1 for high speeds destroying myself.

Comment: @Paul In my long ago cycling days we would on occasion place a bicycle upside down on the ground on its seat and handlebars and turn the pedals at high speed. As there is no road load the speed limit is probably set by stupidity and daring than the speed that you can turn the pedals at.
- FWIW: I now have no idea why we did the above. Maybe it was something that happened after puncture repairs or ...?:-)

Comment: Thanks for the cheer, I don´t understand it either...
As for your idea: The hub dynamo is on the front wheel, the pedals are traditionally connected to the back wheel, so no help from this side

Comment: @Paul <insanity mode on> Largish sanding foam drum thingy on an electric drill held against inverted front wheel MAY produce adequate speed. Quick mental calc say about 2400 RPM needed with ~ 200mm dia disk. So even a 1450 RPM 1 phase AC motor not fast enough without a bigger driving drum. </in .....    agh...........